# Zoom on separate images Android Studio

Tags: java, android, zooming

I am working on an Android Studio project and I have the following problem.

I have an `ImageView` that takes up the whole screen. On top of that, I have another `ImageView`.

The goal is to zoom in/out in the image as one. But I cannot merge the two images since the image on top sometimes is visible and sometimes is not.

What I have tried, is to use the [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) implementation, but if I place the background image as a `PhotoView`, then I cannot place new images on top of that.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Well, you can check if the image on-top is visible, or not. If it is merge them. If not then zoom only in the first image view.